# Как найти позицию вхождения одного вектора во второй

Tags: c++, алгоритм, vector, c++14

*Условия*:

1. Вектор A всегда больше вектора B
2. Вектор B входит в вектор A
3. Вектор A очень большой, в отличие от вектора B

*Нужно*:

Найти позицию вхождения одного вектора в другой

Comment: А просто std::search не катит ? Или для начала проверить через std::includes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения в Вашей задачи (в не отсортированной коллекции) возьмите std::search

Пример кода :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>


int main() {
    std::vector<int> base(10'000'000);
    std::iota(std::begin(base), std::end(base), 0);
    std::rotate(std::begin(base), std::begin(base) + (base.size() / 2) , std::end(base));

    std::vector<int> a(15);
    std::iota(std::begin(a), std::end(a), 777);

    std::vector<int> b(15);
    std::iota(std::begin(b), std::end(b), -777);

    auto res_1{std::search(std::begin(base), std::end(base), std::default_searcher(std::begin(a), std::end(a)))};
    if (res_1 != std::end(base)) {
        std::cout << "sequence found" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "sequence not found" << std::endl;
    }

    auto res_2{std::search(std::begin(base), std::end(base), std::default_searcher(std::begin(b), std::end(b)))};
    if (res_2 != std::end(base)) {
        std::cout << "sequence found" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "sequence not found" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Тут вся соль именно в механизме сравнение подпоследовательности, в примере я написал std::default_searcher но есть еще

```
default_searcher

(C++17)

standard C++ library search algorithm implementation
(class template)
boyer_moore_searcher

(C++17)

Boyer-Moore search algorithm implementation
(class template)
boyer_moore_horspool_searcher

(C++17)

Boyer-Moore-Horspool search algorithm implementation
(class template)
```

Все о них есть тут https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional

Answer (score 2):

Есть такая структура данных, [префиксное дерево](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE) (на англ также `trie`), обычно используется для текстовых данных (с целью поиска подстрок), но может применяться для любых массивов дискретных значений.

Часто эта структура используется в биоинформатике, как раз с теми же условиями – огромные размеры исходного массива, заметно меньшие у искомого. У префиксного дерева есть реализации с оптимизациями для сжатия размера.

Полезные ссылки:

- [Описание на Хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/111874/)
- [Описание и пример реализации на GeeksForHeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-insert-and-search/)

---

> Нужно найти позицию вхождения одного вектора в другой

Узлы префиксного дерево могут иметь булево значение, а могут числовое. В первом случае дерево будет лишь говорить, какие подстроки в строке есть, а каких нет. Во втором можно хранить более детальную информацию, например, позицию подстроки в исходной строке. Это и будет решением задачи в Вашем вопросе.

Comment: да, но это не векторы. А мне нужны именно они.

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG вектор можно считать синонимом массива, т.е, это подходит для префиксного дерева (:

Comment: Кажется, префикс-функция будет оптимальнее? Да и пишется намного проще?

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, для разового расчёта префикс-функция действительно будет лучше. Префиксное дерево больше пойдёт для случаев, когда по одной исходной строке нужно искать много разных подстрок.

Comment: @AivanF. Ваш ответ - это методика решений другой задачи

Comment: @Andrey не совсем, построив префиксное дерево заданной глубины (равной длине искомых подстрок/массивов) можно легко находить подстроки и места их вхождений.

Comment: @AivanF. задача автора решается в 3 строчки через алгоритмы stl

Answer (score 2):

Если искомый вектор маленький или вероятность частичного его совпадения с куском основного не слишком велика, то я бы использовал самый тупой алгоритм: перебираем первый символ вектора A и пытаемся начиная с него накладывать вектор B и сравнивать до тех пор, пока вектор не закончится или пока не будет найдено различие. В худшем случае работать будет за произведение длин, но такие данные надо подбирать намеренно.

Если же это вариант не подходит, то можно воспользоваться [префикс-функцией](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/prefix_function). Замечу, что конкатенированную строку в памяти хранить не обязательно, а значения префикс-функции нужны только для искомой строки (короткой), а для длинной можно считать только текущее значение, не сохраняя его в массив. Здесь асимптотика гарантированна линейная.

Comment: Все это уже есть в stl

Comment: @Andrey, префикс-функции вроде нет?

Comment: Есть оптимизации по хешу

Comment: @Andrey, какие оптимизации?

Comment: когда сравнивается хеш искомых данных

Comment: @Andrey, что-то подозрительно...